# Do you add your modifiers to attack rolls when you fight with two weapons?

Tags: dnd-5e, attack, two-weapon-fighting, attack-roll, fighting-style

I plan on making a dual wielding barbarian/fighter, and in fighter's fighting style it says that this style allows me to add modifiers to damage rolls for second weapon. But do I get a bonus for the second attack itself, or does everyone already have it? If not, is there something that allows me to add it?

P.s. apologies for bad english.

Comment: I have closed your question as I feel it has effectively been asked before. Note that this isn't a bad thing, it actually helps people find those questions above. That said, if you feel those questions do *not* answer yours, feel free to explain why in a comment or an [edit] since your question can always be reopened

Comment: Oh, sorry. For some reason I couldn't find the same topic when I was about to send my question. If it is a duplicate, should I delete it or leave it as it is for people to find relevant answers?

Comment: @Anki I'd say just leave it up, it doesn't do any harm by being here, and may do some good by redirecting others as well